# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Permission denied (while saving the image via "CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll()")

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

[ss from my debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zud5t.png)

I am getting Permission denied when trying to save the image to the gallery via "CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll()" from react native. my code is below==>

```
takePicture = async function() {
if (this.camera) {
  const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
  let saveResult = CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri);
  console.warn('takePicture ', saveResult);
  console.warn('picture url ', data.uri);
}
```

};

i have taken permissions from android manifest and ios by adding required codes.
(On Android)
[android manifest permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Uw9.png)

even in ios i am getting the same permission denied error. what should i do to work it. i don't wanna try RN File system.

Comment: Have you tried using `let saveResult = await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri);`?

Comment: @MarvinKlar i tried them all. gives me the same error even before now.
`YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Permission denied
Error: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

i have gone through lots of resources and finally got the reason. Somehow my manifest permission didn't get the permission for writing external permission as below.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

so what i did i added runtime permission for the external writing and it works fine. i use **PermissionsAndroid** from **react-native**.

codes are below =>

```
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
        message:
          "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
          "so you can take awesome pictures.",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera");

      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
      let saveResult = CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri);
      console.warn("takePicture ", saveResult);
      console.warn("picture url ", data.uri);
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the permissions in runtime, the problem persisted until I did the below:

Add the code below into `application` in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifesst.xml`:

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
```